# OrmLiteConnectionFactory.cs not found error

Tags: .net, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to use `OrmLite` with SQL Server in ServiceStack Framework of .net. Now the tables are getting created and also i am able to insert the values into the table but while debugging i am getting a message `You need to OrmLiteConnectionFactory.cs to view the source for the current call Stack frame`.I am using ServiceStack as well as OrmLite for the first time not sure what is this for.Please help me to resolve this .Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't debug into external libraries without the necessary Debug Symbols for that library. The ServiceStack debug symbols are published on [symbolsource.org](http://symbolsource.org) however symbolsource.org has been unreliable for weeks so it's best you just skip over trying to debug external libraries by [checking the Just My Code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn457346.aspx) option in VS.NET.

Other options if you really want to debug ServiceStack libraries is to use the [v4.0.44 .pdb symbols](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Assets/tree/master/nuget) published in the Assets repo. Another option is to clone the [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) GitHub repository which has all the source code for OrmLite.